# How to show children pages as array

Tags: theme-development, templates, page-template, child-theme, child-pages

I am creating a template that would display children pages of a parent page.

> Employees
>
> ♦ Managers
>
> ♦ IT guys
>
> ♦ Designers

I want parent page (employees) to display its children pages.

I've tried this: (in functions.php)

```
function wpb_list_child_pages() { 

global $post; 

if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )

    $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
else
    $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );

if ( $childpages ) {

    $string = '<ul>' . $childpages . '</ul>';
}

return $string;

}

add_shortcode('wpb_childpages', 'wpb_list_child_pages');
```

and declaration in my page's template:

```
echo wpb_list_child_pages();
```

I get a list of children pages but as a list (of course, there is nothing wrong with the code)

I want to enlist children as items of an array so that I can do something like this:

```
$page1 = childrenID[0];
$page2 = childrenID[1];
$page3 = childrenID[2];
```

I want this so that I can theme children pages (by ID) on their parent page.

I hope I am clear.

**Update**

After using this:
`global $post;
$parent_id = the_ID();

$children = get_posts(array(
    'post_parent' => $parent_id,
    'fields' => 'ids'
));

echo $string = '

' . implode('

', $children) . '

';`

I am getting a list of IDs which are of some posts and not pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `get_posts` function.

```
global $post;
$parent_id = $post->ID;

$children = get_posts(array(
    'post_parent' => $parent_id,
    'fields' => 'ids'
));

$string = '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $children) . '</li></ul>';
```

- [get_posts function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)
- [WP_Query class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: I used `the_ID()` function instead of `$post->ID;` in line 2. Is that Okay?

Comment: `the_ID()` prints id, use  `get_the_ID()` instead

Comment: get_the_ID() shows blank list $string when I print it.

Comment: the_ID() and get_the_ID() will only works inside loop. Otherwise you have to call global $post or get it from query vars to get post id

Comment: i used global $post. Also I'm getting posts as children and not pages.